# Find Maximum Radius Circle Everywhere Between Two Lines

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, geometry

I have two sine waves, as pictured below. Sometimes they are identical waves, just shifted in the y-axis. Other times the sine waves have different period / amplitude etc.

[image]

I need to find the **maximum radius circle** that can fit between the two lines *everywhere* along the lines (discretized by the resolution that I generated the lines).

What is the best way to do this? Is there a faster way than iteratively creating a circle tangent to the bottom curve and stepping up in radius until intersection with the upper curve, at every point?

Comment: This sounds like a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: The maximum circle radius is one half of the minimum distance between the lines.  Depending on how you have quantized the lines, you could just compute the distance between every pair of points and take the minimum.  And that doesn't mean points where x is equal; it means the first point of line 1 vs every point in line 2.

Comment: @TimRoberts unfortunately it is not that simply. It is 1/2 the distance of the normal line connecting the two lines, which is much harder to calculate.

Comment: I doubt there's an analytic way to do this; you'll probably be forced to use a little systematic guess-and-check. However, that doesn't mean you need to test every point. You could use any number of optimization methods. You might try a gradient descent approach, and seed it with (for example)10 values along the length of one curve. Methods like this always take some parameter tuning to get good performance/results, but I bet you could make it significantly faster than a check at every point.

Comment: If you did every pair of points, you'd get that normal.  As I said, that only works if the number of points is reasonable, since it's an O(N^2) operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this a the complete answer, but it may contain a few useful ideas. (There is some math, but I think the code is also important, so I think SO is a reasonable place for this question.)

[image]
[image]

There may be multiple solutions to the last equation, but in practice [`scipy.optimize.newton`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html) seems to converge to the circle of minimum radius. Also, it's vectorized, so you can solve for several circles at once.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
colors = list(mcolors.TABLEAU_COLORS.values())

# amplitude, angular frequency, phase, and y-offsets
params1 = 1, 1, 0, 0
params2 = 0.5, 0.5, 1, 2

# Sinusoid
def y(x, params):
    A, w, p, y = params
    return A*np.cos(w*x + p) + y

# Derivative of Sinusoid
def dy(x, params):
    A, w, p, y = params
    return -w*A*np.sin(w*x + p)

# Angle of Sinusoid Surface Normal
def phi(x, params):
    return np.arctan2(-1, dy(x, params))

# Radius of circle required given y-coordinates
def ry(y1, y2, phi1, phi2):
    return (y2 - y1)/(np.sin(phi1) + np.sin(phi2))

# Radius of circle required given x-coordinates
def rx(x1, x2, phi1, phi2):
    return (x2 - x1)/(np.cos(phi1) + np.cos(phi2))

# At the solution, the radius of the circle given y-coordinates
# must agree with the radius of the circle given x-coordinates
def f(x2, x1):
    y1, y2 = y(x1, params1), y(x2, params2)
    phi1, phi2 = phi(x1, params1), phi(x2, params2)
    return rx(x1, x2, phi1, phi2) - ry(y1, y2, phi1, phi2)

# Coordinate of center of circle
def x0y0(x1, r):
    y1 = y(x1, params1)
    phi1 = phi(x1, params1)
    return (x1 + r*np.cos(phi1), y1 + r*np.sin(phi1))

# Plot Sinusoids
t_plot = np.linspace(0, 15, 300)
y1 = y(t_plot, params1)
y2 = y(t_plot, params2)
plt.plot(t_plot, y1, 'k', t_plot, y2, 'k')
ax = plt.gca()
plt.ylim(-2, 4)
plt.axis('equal')

# Coordinates on sinusoid 1
x1 = np.asarray([1, 4.5, 7, 11, 13])
y1 = y(x1, params1)

# X-coordinates on sinusoid 2
x2 = newton(f, x1, args=(x1,))
y2 = y(x2, params2)

# Circle radii and centers
phi1 = phi(x1, params1)
phi2 = phi(x2, params2)
r = rx(x1, x2, phi1, phi2)
x0, y0 = x0y0(x1, r)

for i in range(len(x1)):
    color = colors[i]

    # Mark points on curve
    plt.plot(x1[i], y1[i], color, marker='*')
    plt.plot(x2[i], y2[i], color, marker='*')

    # Plot circles 
    circle = plt.Circle((x0[i], y0[i]), r[i], color=color, fill=False)
    ax.add_patch(circle)
```

[image]

Two caveats:

- `scipy.optimize.newton` is not guaranteed to converge, and even if it does, it is not guaranteed to converge to the circle with minimum radius (unless it can be proven otherwise...). If it is not reliable for your particular parameters but you like the approach, consider posting a more specific question about how to reliably solve the relevant equations numerically. It may just be a matter of solving for one circle and using that as the guess for the next circle.
- This code doesn't consider the possibility of the circle intersecting with a second point on the lower curve before it touches the upper curve. I couldn't tell from the problem statement if this was required because the question mentioned "stepping up in radius until intersection with the upper curve". This is easy enough to check, though, due to symmetry of the convex portion of the sinusoid.

Comment: This is fantastic, I appreciate the math basis and the code implementation. One thing, I do need it to ensure the tangent circle is not intersecting ANYWHERE, including other points on the lower curve. How could the above answer be modified to ensure there is no intersection absolutely anywhere on both curves?

Comment: I can expand in the answer later, but this part is easier because we know where the circle would first intersect the lower curve: the point at the same y-coordinate on the opposite side of the sinusoid trough. At that point, the derivative has the opposite sign, so the surface normal is flipped about the vertical axis. Skipping ahead, 2r cos φ = Δ, where Δ is the difference in x-coordinates of these points. If this radius is smaller than the radius of the circle that is tangent to the other curve, this is the circle we're interested in.

Comment: I think I am following your logic. I will try and implement but look forward to your updates as well. For example, check point x = 9

Comment: Any idea why this would give negative radii? Do I just need to take the `abs()` of the returned radius from `rx()`?

Comment: Yup, I just kept the sign because it was useful for plotting. The absolute value is what you want. It comes from the fact that sometimes the point you're starting with is on the left of the trough, and sometimes it's on the right.

Comment: I can't be sure. Note that I used variables `y1` and `y2` for two different things - first plotting the curves, then as specific points of tangency on the sinusoids. (Not great practice, but this wasn't written as production code.) Could that be causing confusion? Or can you provide the parameters of your sinusoids and some points on the lower curve you're interested in? (And I'm curious if you can give a hint about what this is for?)

Comment: That was it... thank you. Sorry, I deleted my previous comment before I saw your response.

Comment: How could you extend this to an arbitrary curve, not just sine/cosine, that is defined by an x-array and a y-array?

Comment: I thnk the simplest thing would be to generate a smooth interpolant like a cubic spline. (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicHermiteSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.CubicHermiteSpline). You differentiate those (`derivative` method), and everything after that should be the same (assuming Newton converges). Then you can find the closest of the original points, if needed. If the points are too sparse to approximate a smooth curve, then you just try all of them, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer finds the circle (hopefully the smallest ones) that is tangent to a point on the lower curve and a point on the upper curve. To keep the logic clear, I'm posting a complementary answer that finds the radius of the smallest circle tangent to two points on the lower curve.

The essential idea is illustrated with this figure:
[image]

We know that the circle tangent to the curve at a point A will be tangent at a point B with the same y-coordinate. The x-coordinate of point B is found by symmetry around the trough (local minimum) of the sinusoid. Let the center of the circle be point C. The radius from C to A and the radius from C to B form two legs of an iscoceles triangle; the third leg is the chord of the circle between A and B. We also know the angles: ∠CAB = ∠CBA = φ, the angle of the curve's surface normal at A. Given these angles and the the chord length AB, we can solve for the radius AC = BC (taking the absolute value in case it's negative).

Now you have a pair of radii corresponding with each point: one is of the circle tangent to one point on each curve (from the previous answer), one is of the circle tangent to two points on the same (lower) curve. The circle you are interested in is the one with the smaller of the two radii.

```py
# ... after executing code above

_, w1, p1, _ = params1

# Phase of point A along curve 1
th1 = w1*x1 + p1
# Phase of the previous crest of curve 1
crest = (th1 // (2*np.pi)) * 2*np.pi
# Phase of the next crest of curve 1
crest_opposite = crest + 2*np.pi
# Phase of point B opposite trough of curve 1
# (this is the second point where the circle is tangent to the curve)
th1_opposite = crest_opposite - (th1 - crest)
# x-coordinate of point on opposite trough
x1_opposite = (th1_opposite - p1)/w1
# Distance between the points of tangency
delta = x1_opposite - x1
# Radius of the circle tangent to curve at both points
r = delta/(2 * np.cos(phi1))  # leave the sign for plotting
# Center of circle tangent to curve at both points
x0 = x1 + r * np.cos(phi1)
y0 = y1 + r * np.sin(phi1)

# Plot Sinusoids
t_plot = np.linspace(0, 20, 300)
y1 = y(t_plot, params1)
y2 = y(t_plot, params2)
plt.plot(t_plot, y1, 'k', t_plot, y2, 'k')
ax = plt.gca()
plt.ylim(-2, 4)
plt.axis('equal')

# Coordinates on sinusoid 1
x1 = np.asarray([1, 4.5, 7, 11, 13])
y1 = y(x1, params1)

for i in range(len(x1)):
    color = colors[i]

    # Mark points on curve
    plt.plot(x1[i], yx1[i], color, marker='*')
    plt.plot(x1_opposite[i], yx1[i], color, marker='*')

    # Plot circles
    circle = plt.Circle((x0[i], y0[i]), r[i], color=color, fill=False)
    ax.add_patch(circle)
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work well, until your curves are far enough apart where neither of these methods catches the circle intersection in some location with the upper curve. For example, try:
`params1 = 3.466, 0.586, -1.571, 3.466` and `params2 = 3.466, 0.586, -1.571, 13.398`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "neither of these methods...". This answer is about finding tangency with the same curve. I'm not observing any trouble with those parameters. Only the first answer attempts to find tangency with the top curve - but yes, sometimes the solver has trouble finding the intersection with the top curve that you're looking for. The simplest solution is to try a few initial guesses in the call to `newton`. If you try enough points, you're almost certain for at least one guess to converge to the point you're looking for (the one with the smallest radius).

Comment: If the sinusoids are always going to be the sample amplitude, frequency, and phase, there may be a way to exploit that, e.g. to choose good guesses, or maybe you can put bounds on where the tangency point would be and use a bracketing rootfinder.